# Why do we call completion on main thread in asynchronous function?

Tags: swift, concurrency

For example in this function,

```
func asyncAdd(_ input: (Int, Int),
runQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated),
completionQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.main,
completion: @escaping (Result<Int, SlowAddError>) -> ()) {
runQueue.async {
    let result = input.0 + input.1
    completionQueue.async {
        completion(result)
    }
 }
}
```

Why is completionQueue, the main thread, have to be where the completion is called. Could we not just call the completion on a background thread?

Comment: It depends what the completion handler actually does. Typically you see this when callbacks are used to modify the UI, which in iOS can only be done from the main thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it's often convenient to call completion handlers on the main queue, since it's common to want to update the UI, and calling UI updaters on the wrong queue is a common bug.

It is not required, nor even universally recommended, to make general-purpose async functions call back on the main queue. But for certain systems where the use cases are well-known, it's very convenient and helps prevent bugs.

The above example, of course, is not useful, and would be very unlikely to be found in production code. But that doesn't change the utility in specialized cases. Another common pattern is for the caller to pass a completion queue. That's also fine, particularly for very general-purpose tools (such as URLSession, which uses this approach).

Answer (score 0):

"Could we not just call the completion on a background thread?"

Well, in the general case I would vote for "no" if this background thread is a *worker thread*. You have to decide from case to case whether you can do this safely or not:

The object that asynchronously performs the task - lets call it "operation", may have special requirements on the worker threads (or dispatch queues) where the task is performed. This could include a special quality of service level (see [DispatchQoS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqos)), the fact that it is a serial queue, etc. Worker threads are internal to the "Operation" for dedicated use to run *their* tasks, but possibly not suited to run other tasks or functions.

When the operation calls the completion handler on its worker thread, it has no more control of what happens with their worker threads. The client could for example directly perform extended CPU intensive calculations, thereby stalling the operation because its worker thread is now busy and has to wait until the client's completion handler completed. These calculation may also run on the QoS defined by the operation which is not suitable at all for the client's requirements.

So, that all could introduce performance issues into a complex asynchronous system or make it even unpredictable in its behaviour.

An example is URLSession, which does not call the completion handler on its internal worker thread, but on a dedicated "callback" OperationQueue. When using URLSession you either provide it, or URLSession will create one for you.